# LINQ Join with Group By

Tags: linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have a table structure like following

```
Table_A

 Id      Description 

 1           A
 2           B
 3           C
 4           D

Table_B

 Table_A_Id   Id    Description

    1          1        A
    1          2        B
    2          3        C
    2          4        D
    3          5        E
    3          6        F
    4          7        G
    4          8        H
    4          9        I
    4         10        J
```

I want to JOIN them in a way to get List of following Class

```
 Public Resultset
{
     public Table_A table_a {get;set;}
     public List<Table_B> table_b {get;set;}
}
```

// suppose we have classes for Table_A and Table_B as per their table definition

Following is my try

```
var filter [] = {1,3,5}; 

var query = from  a in context.Table_A
            joins b in context.Table_B
            on a.Id equals b.Table_A_id
            where filter.Contains(b.Id) 
            // Need something here perhaps to group it to get desired results
            Select new ResultSet()
            {
              // what to do here
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following group by:

```
var query = from  a in context.Table_A
            joins b in context.Table_B
            on a.Id equals b.Table_A_id
            where filter.Contains(b.Id) 
            group new{A=a, B=b } by a.Id into g
            select new ResultSet()
            {
               table_a=g.FirstOrDefault().A,
               table_b=g.Select(e=>e.B).ToList()
            };
```

Another way if you were using [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) between those entities:

```
var query = from  b in context.Table_B
            where filter.Contains(b.Id)
            group b by b.Table_A_id into g
            select new ResultSet()
            {
               table_a=g.FirstOrDefault().A,
               table_b=g.ToList()
            };
```

Comment: where filter.Contains(b.Id) won't work after using into bs. What should be passed to Contains method?

Comment: I think Where clause is not working. Doesn't have any effect. I want only those Table_A rows which are true for Filter

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications, try with that group by

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a simple [Group Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
var filter = new [] { 1, 3, 5 }; 

var query = from  a in context.Table_A
            join b in (from b in context.Table_B where filter.Contains(b.Id) select b)
            on a.Id equals b.Table_A_id into items_B
            select new ResultSet
            {
                table_a = a,
                table_b = items_B.ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev, I suggested the same solution at first (check my second edit), but the OP told me It didn't work (check his second comment in my solution). I had my doubts that don't get the expected result, but he said he was getting Table_A rows which didn't belong to the result he was expecting. That's way I suggested a new solution using a group by. But now that I saw your solution, I don't understand why he said it didn't work.

Comment: @octavioccl Hi, thanks for the info. And no problem, I also don't believe that, but after all it's OP problem, not ours :) Cheers.

Comment: That's true ;). Anyways you have my vote, this is definitely a better solution ;)

Comment: He-he, now as I saw the history, looks like I'm duplicating one of the your versions, so I guess I have to upvote it too :)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated ;)